# Slick.js repeat event for multiple sliders

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I am using slick.js for a long scroll with multiple sliders. Each slider responds to click events set by links above it, using the slickGoTo method as navigation.

I want to add an active class to the links afterChange of each slide whether by swiping or slicking the slick prev/next arrows. Ive got it working on the first slider on the page, but it doesnt for the subsequent sliders.

The simple fix would be slider syncing, but I havent been able to get it to work when there are multiple of the same slider class in the way the slider syncing is shown in [the slick documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="leak-slider">
    <div class="slider-dots">
        <a class="link pulse active">link 1 </a>
    </div> <!-- /.slider-dots -->
    <div class="slider-dots">
        <a class="link pulse active">link 2 </a>
    </div> <!-- /.slider-dots -->
    <div class="slider-dots">
        <a class="link pulse active">link 3 </a>
    </div> <!-- /.slider-dots -->
</div>

<div class="expanded-slider">
    <div class="expanded-content">
        <h3 class="expanded-title">Title of each slide</h3>

        <p>content</p>
    </div>  <!-- /.expanded-content -->

    <div class="expanded-content">
        <h3 class="expanded-title">Title of each slide</h3>

        <p>content</p>
    </div>  <!-- /.expanded-content -->

    <div class="expanded-content">
        <h3 class="expanded-title">Title of each slide</h3>

        <p>content</p>
    </div>  <!-- /.expanded-content -->
</div> <!-- /.expanded-slider -->
```

The above markup is wrapped in containers for each section of the page

**jQuery**

```
  var $expandedSlider = $('.expanded-slider').slick({
    arrows: true,
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });

  $('.slider-dots').on('click', function(){
    var slideIndex = $(this).index(),
      dot = $(this),
      dotLink = dot.children('.link'),
      currentSlide = $expandedSlider.slick('slickCurrentSlide');

    // toggle active class on click of dots
    dotLink.addClass('active');
    dot.siblings().children('.link').removeClass('active');

    //Navigate to Slide
    $expandedSlider.slick('slickGoTo', parseInt( slideIndex ));
  });

  // toggle active class on change of slide
  $expandedSlider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, direction){
    var slider = $(this),
      currentSlide = slider.slick('slickCurrentSlide'),
      dot = $('.slider-dots').eq(currentSlide),
      dotLink = dot.children('.link');

    dotLink.addClass('active');
    dot.siblings().children('.link').removeClass('active');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Concluded that the slick afterchange method listens to all change events within the the initialized class. so with multiple sliders using the same class, its not possible to have the change event occur only on that slider..